# Connecting cubes with large datasets to Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Hi I am facing problem when connecting cubes with large datasets to Power BI, through Power BI Desktop. The smallest cube I want to connect is based on fact table having 5 Million rows. It gives me a timeout expired error,error text is "The XML for Analysis Services Request time out before it was completed". I have installed Power BI Desktop on the same machine on which SSAS is installed.

However I have tried with some smaller cubes and they are okay. Somehow I was able to connect a cube with 5 million rows, but I had to leave some of dimensions which were having large number of records.

Answer (score 0):

SSAS will struggle to serve results at that volume to Power BI or most other client tools - it's not how SSAS was designed.

I would look at the Power BI Enterprise Gateway with a Live connection.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-gateway-enterprise/

Alternatively you could reduce the scope of the requests, or connect directly to the underlying datasource which SSAS is reading e.g. SQL database.